# How can I register JMX support for EhCache in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, ehcache, jmx

I'm trying to configure EhCache for JMX. Looks like I need only use EhCacheManager and register it for mBeanServer.

Here is my configs:

```
@Configuration
public class EhcacheConf {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager getEhCacheManager() {
        return getEhCacheFactory().getObject();
    }

    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean getEhCacheFactory() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        factoryBean.setShared(true);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ManagementService managementService() {
        return new ManagementService(getEhCacheManager(),
                mbeanServer(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true);
    }

    @Bean
    public MBeanServer mbeanServer() {
        MBeanServerFactoryBean mBeanServerFactoryBean = new MBeanServerFactoryBean();
        mBeanServerFactoryBean.setLocateExistingServerIfPossible(true);
        return mBeanServerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

}
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
    datasource:
      url: "jdbc:h2:file:~/testdb"
      username: sa
      password: sa
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create-drop
    cache:
      type: ehcache
      ehcache:
        config: classpath:ehcache.xml

endpoints:
  jmx:
    domain: quiz
    unique-names: true
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">

    <cache name="Folder"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
           eternal="false"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Caching -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you don't need all that stuff to configure EhCache 2.x with Spring Boot. All you need really is `@EnableCaching` the ehcache dependency and your `ehcache.xml` configuration file at the usual location.

Your config is also overriding the `MBeanServer` which switches off what Spring Boot does for you there.

A sample is worth a thousand words anyway, so [I've created one for you](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-ehcache-jmx).

Edit: Thanks to Timur Milovanov to mention that this sample doesn't unregister MBeans on shutdown, I've updated the sample to fix that.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sample is awesome!

Comment: Sample from Nicoll does not unregister mbean on context stop. 
A static method javadoc: _A convenience static method which creates... This one is provided for backward compatibility_
It may be better to define bean and use constructor of `ManagementService`. In bean definition you should define init/destroy methods: `@Bean(initMethod="init", destroyMethod="dispose")`. This `ManagementService#dispose` method unregister cache-related instances from MBeanServer. PS: unregister might be important if you deploy/undeploy application in container (tomcat,jetty) without that container restart

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimurMilovanov, I've updated the sample.